# OpenAM Session Failure

Tags: apache, openam

I m getting an invalid session ID response for the agent request to OpenAM. This works fine for the initial call, 302 happens for the subsequent calls with different token. When I checked in the console the session was listed there and curl to get the user from session also works fine.

I am using OpenAM version : OpenAM 11.0.3 (2015-March-02 15:50) with Web Policy Agent 4.0.0. Here is the agent debug log looks like.

The session is valid and its showing in the console sessions tab. Also curl to get ID from session works fine.

```
v1/Endpoint/Service.wsdl (ignoring pathinfo: no), entry status: success
2019-12-16 23:56:13.600 +0000 WARNING [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372] am_get_session_policy_cache_entry(): failed to locate data for a key (AQIC5wM2LY4SfczGLQ1DDuEKbdwlTLEr4jy8i3dP7PJHaAo.*AAJTSQACMDEAAlNLABQtNDUxOTQxMTA0MTQzNjk3Mzc5Nw..*, WebSessionID=10.16.144.64.1576481325860310)
2019-12-16 23:56:13.600 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/process.c:938] validate_policy(): get session cache status: not found
2019-12-16 23:56:13.600 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/utility.c:1651] get_valid_openam_url(): active OpenAM service url: https://www-devam.domain.co.uk:18081/opensso (0)
2019-12-16 23:56:13.600 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/utility.c:1756] am_timer(): getaddrinfo took 0 seconds
2019-12-16 23:56:13.601 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/net_client.c:496] sync_connect(): connected to www-devam.domain.co.uk:18081 (IPv4)
2019-12-16 23:56:13.601 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/net_client_ssl.c:590] net_ssl_msg_callback(): SSLv2/v3 write client hello B (23WCHB)
2019-12-16 23:56:13.601 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/net_ops.c:559] send_session_request(): sending 752 bytes
2019-12-16 23:56:13.613 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/net_client_ssl.c:590] net_ssl_msg_callback(): SSLv3 read server hello B (3RSH_B)
2019-12-16 23:56:13.613 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/net_client_ssl.c:590] net_ssl_msg_callback(): SSLv3 read server certificate B (3RSC_B)
2019-12-16 23:56:13.613 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/net_client_ssl.c:590] net_ssl_msg_callback(): SSLv3 read server key exchange B (3RSKEB)
2019-12-16 23:56:13.613 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/net_client_ssl.c:331] show_server_cert(): server certificate subject: /C=DE/O=Org/CN=www-devam.domain.co.uk
2019-12-16 23:56:13.613 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/net_client_ssl.c:338] show_server_cert(): server certificate issuer: /C=DE/O=Org/CN=OrgInfrastructure CA V
2019-12-16 23:56:13.613 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/net_client_ssl.c:590] net_ssl_msg_callback(): SSLv3 read server certificate request B (3RCR_B)
2019-12-16 23:56:13.624 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/net_client_ssl.c:590] net_ssl_msg_callback(): SSLv3 write client key exchange B (3WCKEB)
2019-12-16 23:56:13.624 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/net_client_ssl.c:590] net_ssl_msg_callback(): SSLv3 write change cipher spec B (3WCCSB)
2019-12-16 23:56:13.624 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/net_client_ssl.c:590] net_ssl_msg_callback(): SSLv3 write finished B (3WFINB)
2019-12-16 23:56:13.628 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/net_client_ssl.c:590] net_ssl_msg_callback(): SSLv3 read finished A (3RFINA)
2019-12-16 23:56:13.628 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/net_client_ssl.c:590] net_ssl_msg_callback(): SSLv3 read finished B (3RFINB)
2019-12-16 23:56:13.630 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/net_ops.c:577] send_session_request(): response status code: 200
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ResponseSet vers="1.0" svcid="session" reqid="0">
<Response><![CDATA[<SessionResponse vers="1.0" reqid="1">
<GetSession>
<Exception>AQIC5wM2LY4SfczGLQ1DDuEKbdwlTLEr4jy8i3dP7PJHaAo.*AAJTSQACMDEAAlNLABQtNDUxOTQxMTA0MTQzNjk3Mzc5Nw..*, WebSessionID=10.16.144.64.1576481325860310 Invalid session ID.AQIC5wM2LY4SfczGLQ1DDuEKbdwlTLEr4jy8i3dP7PJHaAo.*AAJTSQACMDEAAlNLABQtNDUxOTQxMTA0MTQzNjk3Mzc5Nw..*, WebSessionID=10.16.144.64.1576481325860310</Exception>
</GetSession>
</SessionResponse>]]></Response>
</ResponseSet>
2019-12-16 23:56:13.630 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/net_ops.c:598] send_session_request(): status: invalid session
2019-12-16 23:56:13.630 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/net_ops.c:1163] am_agent_policy_request(): closing connection after failure
2019-12-16 23:56:13.630 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/net_client_ssl.c:590] net_ssl_msg_callback(): SSL negotiation finished successfully (SSLOK )
2019-12-16 23:56:13.630 +0000 WARNING [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372] validate_policy(): retry 0 (remote session/policy call failure: invalid session)
2019-12-16 23:56:13.630 +0000 WARNING [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372] am_remove_cache_entry(): cache data is not available (AQIC5wM2LY4SfczGLQ1DDuEKbdwlTLEr4jy8i3dP7PJHaAo.*AAJTSQACMDEAAlNLABQtNDUxOTQxMTA0MTQzNjk3Mzc5Nw..*, WebSessionID=10.16.144.64.1576481325860310)
2019-12-16 23:56:13.630 +0000 DEBUG [0x7fbbad2e0700:25372][source/process.c:1707] handle_exit(): (entry status: invalid session)
```

Comment: As there are several OpenAM forks currently available, please provide OpenAM fork, OpenAM version, fork of agent, type of agent, agent version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bernhard. I have edited my original post to include the details. Could you please have a look?

Comment: Is there only one OpenAM instance or multiple ones? In case there are multiple instances, have you ensured that cross-talk is working fine?

Comment: Hi Bernard, There is only one OpenAM instance running. 302 happens only for subsequent calls. The very first call for a resource is successful and we are trying to access another resource within a SOAP Webservice by generating new session with a different user. This is where the issue happens. It was working fine when we used jee agent with filters. Now we removed jee agent and maintained Web agent only.